# Infinite list with Sencha Touch 2.3

Tags: javascript, listview, extjs, sencha-touch

I'm developping a chat interface and trying to obtain the infinite list effect with Sencha Touch list component. I want to dynamically load older messages when the user scrolls up.

```
myList.getStore().insert(0,itemsArray);
```

The problem :
When I insert new items at the top of the list it automatically scrolls to the top. Is there a way to avoid it ?

Answer (score 2):

This should be fixed by setting the list's `scrollToTopOnRefresh` config option to `false`

see http://docs-origin.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/api/Ext.dataview.List-cfg-scrollToTopOnRefresh